# Write the conservation equation for the heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Write the conservation equation for the heat equation $ \large \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{k}{r^2} \frac{\partial }{\partial r} (r^2 \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}) \ $ and solve it with respect to the condition $ \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}(a)=\alpha , \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}(b)=\beta \ $ for equilibrium heat equation .

**Answer:**

The conservation equation should be

$ \frac{d}{dt} \int_a^b u dr=\int_a^b  \frac{k}{r^2} \frac{\partial }{\partial r} (r^2 \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}) dr \ $

But how to evaluate the integral and conclude for what values of $ a, \ b \ $ , the equlibrium solution exists.

Look at for equilibrium solution , $ u \ $ independent of $ t =time \ $

ie., $ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=0 \ $

**please help me out**

Comment: It seems integration by parts works here, $\frac{k}{r^2}=u$ and $\frac{\partial }{\partial r} (r^2 \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}) =dv$.

Comment: Is that equation for conservation right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have the radial part of the Laplacian in spherical coordinates. If that is the case, then you need to be using the weight that would come from the spherical volume element $r^2\sin\theta drd\theta d\phi$. So I suspect that the correct heat expression for a solution with only radial dependence would be
$$
        \int_{a}^{b}k\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)r^2 dr = \left.k r^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right|_{a}^{b}.
$$
That expression makes sense in terms of dimensional analysis. $r^2$ corresponds to surface area of a sphere, and the radial derivative times that would be heat transfer across that sphere. So the expression on the left is conserved if the heat in and out are the same across their respective spherical shells.

Comment: The condition given $ \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}(a)=\alpha , \ \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}(b)=\beta \ $ . Now waht would be the value of $ \alpha , \ \beta \ $ in order the equilibrium solution exists.

Comment: @yourmath Where the right-side evaluation $kr^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}|_{a}^{b}$ is $0$. That is, $b^2\beta = a^2\alpha$, which makes sense when viewed in terms of radial heat across a spherical surface. I have been assuming $k$ is constant in $r$. If that is not the case, then, of course, an equilibrium condition depends on this material property as well.